# Different bayesian networks got the same predicton in bnlearn

Tags: r, bayesian-network

I was trying to build two bayesian networks by 'bnlearn' package in R. Firstly I created models in this way:

```
# create an empty network and add nodes.
g = empty.graph(colnames(data))

# crate edges.
bogus = matrix(c("age", "education", "age", "marital.status", 'native.country', 'race',
                'education', 'occupation', 'marital.status', 'relationship', 'occupation', 'hours.per.week',
                'workclass', 'hours.per.week', 'workclass', 'occupation', 'income', 'race',
                'income', 'native.country', 'income', 'sex', 'income', 'capitial_stat', 'income', 'age',
                'income', 'education', 'income', 'marital.status', 'income', 'relationship', 'income', 'occupation',
                'income', 'workclass', 'income', 'hours.per.week'),
           ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE,
           dimnames = list(NULL, c("from", "to")))

arcs(g) = bogus

g2 = empty.graph(colnames(data))
bogus2 = matrix(c('income', 'race',
                'income', 'native.country', 'income', 'sex', 'income', 'capitial_stat', 'income', 'age',
                'income', 'education', 'income', 'marital.status', 'income', 'relationship', 'income', 'occupation',
                'income', 'workclass', 'income', 'hours.per.week'),
           ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE,
           dimnames = list(NULL, c("from", "to")))
arcs(g2) = bogus2
```

Then, one of my network had the structure like this:

```
 > g

  Random/Generated Bayesian network

  model:
   [income][age|income][workclass|income][sex|income][native.country|income]
   [capitial_stat|income][education|age:income][marital.status|age:income]
   [race|native.country:income][occupation|workclass:education:income]
   [relationship|marital.status:income]
   [hours.per.week|workclass:occupation:income]
  nodes:                                 12
  arcs:                                  19
    undirected arcs:                     0
    directed arcs:                       19
  average markov blanket size:           3.33
  average neighbourhood size:            3.17
  average branching factor:              1.58

  generation algorithm:                  Empty
```

Another one was:

```
> g2

  Random/Generated Bayesian network

  model:
   [income][age|income][workclass|income][education|income]
   [marital.status|income][occupation|income][relationship|income][race|income]
   [sex|income][hours.per.week|income][native.country|income]
   [capitial_stat|income]
  nodes:                                 12
  arcs:                                  11
    undirected arcs:                     0
    directed arcs:                       11
  average markov blanket size:           1.83
  average neighbourhood size:            1.83
  average branching factor:              0.92

  generation algorithm:                  Empty
```

The second one is basically a naive-bayes model I think. I wanted to compare the result of predictions between this two models. So I fitted models and predicted dataset by code below:

```
fit = bn.fit(g, data, method='mle')
pred_my_network = predict(fit, node = "income", data = test)
sum(pred_my_network == test$income)/length(pred_my_network)
```

Here I got an accuracy rate of 0.7543161. But when I did the same thing at the second model, I got the same result of 0.7543161.The code has not many differences except different objects:

```
fit2 = bn.fit(g2, data, method='mle')
pred_my_network2 = predict(fit2, node = "income", data = test)
sum(pred_my_network2 == test$income)/length(pred_my_network2)
```

Finally, I used the naive.bayes function in bnlearn to create model,:

```
bn = naive.bayes(data, "income")
pred_nb = predict(bn, test)
sum(pred_nb == test$income)/length(pred_nb)
```

which gave me a different result of 0.809429. But the sturcture is the same as my second model:

```
> bn

  Bayesian network Classifier

  model:
   [income][age|income][workclass|income][education|income]
   [marital.status|income][occupation|income][relationship|income][race|income]
   [sex|income][hours.per.week|income][native.country|income]
   [capitial_stat|income]
  nodes:                                 12
  arcs:                                  11
    undirected arcs:                     0
    directed arcs:                       11
  average markov blanket size:           1.83
  average neighbourhood size:            1.83
  average branching factor:              0.92

  learning algorithm:                    Naive Bayes Classifier
  training node:                         income
  tests used in the learning procedure:  0
```

Have no idea why this happend. Did I create/fit/predict my model in a wrong way?

Comment: The default predict method for BN's is to use the parent nodes. As income, in g, does not have any parents, the predictions will be at the prior distribution: so if discrete it will predict the mode (the category with the greatest probability), or if Gaussian it will predict the mean. Naive Bayes does  something different.

Comment: You are right. Just changed a node which has different numbers of parents and got different accuracy rate. I misunderstand the way it works totally. Thank you very much.